# How can I take a remote screenshot of a website from a url?

Tags: c#, html, multithreading, html-agility-pack, webpage-screenshot

So I have an application that does:

1. Take n amount of links from SQL
2. Creates a new thread for each link
3. Get HTML code of this website with HTML-Agility-Pack for each thread
4. Saves its data to SQL (image sizes, page size, word count, words etc) and saves this process with its date

This is to check the data on a website and see if there is any changes (like a typo or a problem with images that were previously uploaded) and I want to add a screenshot/thumbnail to these for each page. How can I take a screenshot of the whole page during each thread?

Comment: If you can use PHP there's [Browser Shot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot). There are also a number of commercial options out there that provide their own APIs.

Comment: I don't really know PHP. Is there anything like that for C# that is open source?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too sure about that. All I can suggest is searching Github to see if there is anything.

Comment: @3.14thon: If you ask your question about how to diff two pages again I'll post an answer.. I've written a console app that can output all of the differences between two pages with HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: @caesay Hello, I am not planning to post a question again, I think I found a solution but I can send you a mail if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a screenshot, you need your HTML to be rendered. This is a task for a web browser. As you are looking for a C# solution, you could use CefSharp (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) to render your html in offscreen mode.

Comment: WebBrowser was what I was using for getting HTMLDocument, but it seems to create some problems with multithreading (I was creating a new instance for each thread) so that is why I switched to HTML-Agility-Pack. So while I will try, it feels like I will stumble upon same problem because I need something that can work inside each thread and not create any error like WebBrowser does.

Comment: An entity for turning HTML into a picture is essentially a browser engine core. That's why I think that whatever path you choose, you'll end up using some web browser in some form anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is true. Prateek's suggestion seems to be doable since it creates a new form with its own WebBrowser instead of multiple WebBrowsers without a form (which I think was what was causing the error) so I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, that looks promising. And if it does not work, you might always use a single browser control and a synchronized "render request" queue in your UI thread to make all the rendering for you there and to process the results in other threads.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an interesting app. As you already get the HTML for the entire URL (I would assume the app is running on a machine/server which has internet connectivity):

There are 3 ways you can do this (many more actually).

1. In the Thread - create a System.Windows.Forms.Form object, Add a webbrowser control to its list of Child Controls (Dock = Fill). Make the browser navigate to the url. Once navigation is complete - take the screenshot of the WinForms Dialog.
2. In the thread - launch chrome/IE web browser passing the Url as Command line argument. Wait for sometime in the thread (there isnt a good way to know when rendering finishes). Take the screenshot.
3. In the thread - Use selenium type of .net compatible library - which helps you do web ui testing automation and then do Step #2. You will have more granular control over the web browser using this approach.

Comment: I need this to work inside each thread (if there is 7 threads currently working, I need 7 forms that have 7 webbrowsers that take 7 screenshots) so is the 1st solution a good one to use? Wouldn't it really slow things down? Also when I tried to use WebBrowser before (created a new WebBrowser for each thread) it was causing errors, that is why I switched to HTML-Agility-Pack, so I am not sure if this won't create the same problem. Will still try it if I can't find anything better, thanks!